# neo4j CE 3.0.6 fails to start on mac osx 10.11.6 El Capitan

Tags: macos, neo4j

steps
1. installed via neo4j-community_macos_3_0_6.dmg
2. open neo4j application and press start, resulted in the following

Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@5151e54' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.

from command line

```
./neo4j console
Starting Neo4j.
2016-09-24 13:04:31.277+0000 INFO No SSL certificate found, generating a self-signed certificate..
2016-09-24 13:04:31.671+0000 INFO Starting...
2016-09-24 13:04:32.337+0000 INFO Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2016-09-24 13:04:33.442+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@60ff0404' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@60ff0404' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@60ff0404' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:217)
at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:81)
at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:60)
at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:28)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@60ff0404' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:189)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /Users/tedn/Downloads/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.0.1/data/databases/graph.db
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$32(CommunityNeoServer.java:55)
at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.bolt.transport.NettyServer@55351cd5' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.start(KernelExtensions.java:86)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.helpers.PortBindException: Address localhost:7687 is already in use, cannot bind to it.
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace shows that port 7687 is already in use - you can find out what process is currently using it (most probably you already have an instance of neo4j running):

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:7687 | grep LISTEN

java      3840 cswhite  169u  IPv6 0x34c2fd6eef13996f      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:7687 (LISTEN)
```

And then you can use the process id (2nd column, 3840 in the above)

```
ps -ww -p 3840

 PID TTY           TIME CMD
3840 ttys000    0:19.42 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -cp /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.4/libexec/plugins:/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.4/libexec/conf:/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.4/libexec/lib/*:/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.4/libexec/plugins/* -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:hashCode=5 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=tarball -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint --home-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.4/libexec --config-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.0.4/libexec/conf
```